Lua module luaossl installed successfully with luarocks, stilll require("luaossl") fails
I installed "luaossl" using luarocks. Also installed "http". But Cannot import either from lua prompt.
require("http") fails too.
I tried eval "$(luarocks path)" but that didn't help either.
Here is a screenshot.
    # luarocks install http
    Warning: falling back to curl - install luasec to get native HTTPS support
    Installing https://luarocks.org/http-0.4-0.all.rock

    http 0.4-0 depends on lua >= 5.1 (5.3-1 provided by VM)
    http 0.4-0 depends on compat53 >= 0.3 (0.14.3-1 installed)
    http 0.4-0 depends on bit32 (5.3.5.1-1 installed)
    http 0.4-0 depends on cqueues >= 20161214 (20200726.53-0 installed)
    http 0.4-0 depends on luaossl >= 20161208 (20220711-0 installed)
    http 0.4-0 depends on basexx >= 0.2.0 (0.4.1-1 installed)
    http 0.4-0 depends on lpeg (1.1.0-1 installed)
    http 0.4-0 depends on lpeg_patterns >= 0.5 (0.5-0 installed)
    http 0.4-0 depends on binaryheap >= 0.3 (0.4-1 installed)
    http 0.4-0 depends on fifo (0.2-0 installed)
    http 0.4-0 is now installed in /usr (license: MIT)

    [root@ip-146-69-43-165 ~]# lua
    Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
    > luaossl = require("luaossl")
    stdin:1: module 'luaossl' not found:
            no field package.preload['luaossl']
            no file '/usr/share/lua/5.3/luaossl.lua'
            no file '/usr/share/lua/5.3/luaossl/init.lua'
            no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/luaossl.lua'
            no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/luaossl/init.lua'
            no file './luaossl.lua'
            no file './luaossl/init.lua'
            no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/luaossl.so'
            no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
            no file './luaossl.so'
    stack traceback:
            [C]: in function 'require'
            stdin:1: in main chunk
            [C]: in ?
    > require("http")
    stdin:1: module 'http' not found:
            no field package.preload['http']
            no file '/usr/share/lua/5.3/http.lua'
            no file '/usr/share/lua/5.3/http/init.lua'
            no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/http.lua'
            no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/http/init.lua'
            no file './http.lua'
            no file './http/init.lua'
            no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/http.so'
            no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
            no file './http.so'
    stack traceback:
            [C]: in function 'require'
            stdin:1: in main chunk
            [C]: in ?
    >

As shown in the screenshot, I was expecting both "luaossl" and "http" to load successfully.
